# Sealed class objectInstance R8 null problem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-r8, sealed-class

I have a selaed class that contains object like;

```
sealed class Item(val route:String,val showTopBar: Boolean = false) {
   object Example1: Item(route = "example1")
   object Example2: Item(route = "example2", showTopBar = true)
}
```

When I want to get object list from sealed class with reflection in release mode in my app;

```
val itemList = Item::class.nestedClasses.map {
   it.objectInstance as Item
}
```

it.objectInstance is null in release variant. This error is not existing in debug variant. How to solve this sealed class problem? Any proguard rule?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to reflect on classes you need to have keep rules on the classes you will be reflecting on. In this case `Item` and its subclasses. For the subclasses the instance field `INSTANCE` must also be kept.

The following rules with `<packet>` substituted appropriately should work:

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod
-keep class <packet>.Item
-keep class * extends <packet>.Item {
  ** INSTANCE;
}
```

The `-keepattributes` is not strictly necessary if you are including the default rules provided by the Android Gradle plugin through `getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt")`.

Comment: Thanks bro. You saved me from antipattern and spagetti code.